# How to add a custom step in Magento 1.9 checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, development

anybody here have a guide or tutorial on how to add a new step on magento 1.9CE checkout page?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do many things at coding level. you can check below links which can help you

http://inchoo.net/magento/adding-a-new-tab-under-one-page-checkout-full-working-module/

http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/10/magento-onestep-checkout-add-step/

https://www.fontis.com.au/blog/adding-step-onepage-checkout